# Как сделать <button>, активный только в определённый период времени?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать кнопку `<button enabled>`, чтобы было активно только в рабочее время? Например: с 10:00 до 18:00 была активна кнопка, а после 18:00 неактивна до 10:00.
Нашел только примеры по таймеру.

Comment: Учтите, что все ответы используют локальное время компьютера. Соотвественно кнопку легко включить, изменив время на компьютере. Если вы хотите написать что-то типа защиты - пишите ее на сервере, не полагайтесь только на клиента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var h10_00 = 10,
 h18_00 = 18,
 but_10_18 = document.getElementById('but-10-18');

function checkTime()
{
 var time_yet = new Date().getHours();

 if(time_yet >= h10_00 && time_yet < h18_00)
  but_10_18.removeAttribute('disabled');
 else
  but_10_18.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

 setTimeout(checkTime, 100);
}

checkTime();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="but-10-18" value="Начать поиск" disabled onclick="alert('кнопка работает')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот код выполняет функцию отключения кнопки, но не включения ее назад. Т.е. если пользователь зашел на страницу в 09:59, то в 10:00 кнопки не будет

```
var date, dateHours, interval, 
check = function() {
    /* Получаем время пользователя */
    date = new Date();
    dateHours = date.getHours();

    if (dateHours < 10 || dateHours > 17) {
       //код отключения или удаления кнопки
        /* Останавливаем выполнение функции */
       if (typeof interval != 'undefined') {
           clearInterval(interval);
       }
    }
};
check.call();
/* Выполняем функцию с интервалом 20 секунд */
interval = setInterval(check, 20000);
```

Comment: нужно учесть состояние по умолчанию, юзер сможет клацать кнопку первые 20 сек

Comment: @slowBro, спасибо за замечание